# How to switch between activities using sharedpreferences?

Tags: android

I have created one login page for two users, log in as a user and log in as admin, and save user session using share preferences,
want to switch between two activity using share preference. if logined user is admin it starts admin activity and if logined user is user it starts another activity.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    email = findViewById(R.id.email);
    password = findViewById(R.id.password);
    checkedStatus = findViewById(R.id.checkbox);
    radioGroup2 = findViewById(R.id.workeroruser);
    userData = new ArrayList<>();
    if(SharedPreferences.getmInstance(this).isLoggedIn()){
        if(SharedPreferences.getmInstance(this).getAccountu()=="Admin"){
                finish();
                startActivity(new Intent(this,AdminViewActivity.class));
                return;
         }else if (SharedPreferences.getmInstance(this).getAccountu()=="User"){
              finish();
              startActivity(new Intent(this,UserViewActivity.class));
         }
     }
```

Comment: What is the issue you are having?

Comment: Always the first condition is executed if I log in as User or Admin. it executes the first condition and starts AdminActivity.class.

Answer (score 0):

[Strings are compared using equals method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java), but you are trying to compare them using `==` operator, this is the cause of your issue, You need to update your comparisons as following

```
if(SharedPreferences.getmInstance(this).getAccountu().equals("Admin")){
    startActivity(new Intent(this,AdminViewActivity.class));
    finish();
 }
 else if (SharedPreferences.getmInstance(this).getAccountu().equals("User")){
      finish();
      startActivity(new Intent(this,UserViewActivity.class));
 }
```

This should start your desired `Activity`, given that you have stored correct value in shared pref when user logged in.

Comment: I did this, always the first condition executes, even I log in as a User it saves the session and then starts AdminViewActivity.

Comment: Then you are not correctly updating SharedPrefs when you log in.

Comment: but I can get the user name and email from Sharedprefrences correctly. when I login as User I get user account info and when log in as Admin I get Admin account info.

Comment: What does `SharedPreferences.getmInstance(this).getAccountu()` return in each case?

Comment: public String getAccountu(){
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences=mCtx.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREF_NAME_Worker,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        return sharedPreferences.getString(KEY_ACCOUNT,null); } it return string

Comment: I mean what value it returns, does it return "Admin" in each case?

Comment: Yes it returns Admin, or User

Comment: If it returns `User` then else if block should execute and `UserViewActivity` should start.